# How can I get any controller in UINavigationController?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

How can I get any controller in UINavigationController?
I can easily get top controller using the property topViewController; How can i get for example top -1 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a property of UINavigationController namely "viewControllers" which will work as follows:

```
NSArray *controllers = [navController viewControllers];
```

And now you can access any view controller from the returned array!

Answer (score 1):

By accessing the viewControllers property of UINavigationController you will get an array of pushed viewControllers So now you can access any viewController by indexing array.